# cocos2d-x cannot stop looped sound effect on android device

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x version: cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.1
Android version in eclipse propject: 4.2.2
Device: colorfly E708Q1
Device Android system version: 4.2.2
sound effect type: .mp3

Under IOS, it works well. But under android, it does not. However, it works if I called stopEffect(sndId) serval times. 
Any one know why and how to fix it? Thx ahead!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the sound effect must be preload ahead.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. Still an issue in Cocos2d-x.